# Using Regex in SharePoint

Tags: c#, regex, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Some of the guys I work with created a document library on our SharePoint site that contains roughly 34,000 files that were recovered from various computers within our organization.  When recovering those files, I used regex:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^\d{5}_" + MoveFromToYear_TextBox.Text + "", RegexOptions.Compiled);

string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(foldertomove).Where(path => regex.Match(Path.GetFileName(path)).Success).ToArray();
```

After which I used a foreach loop to go through all of the files and moved them to particular folders based on how they're named (they all have the same naming convention.)  When the files were uploaded to SharePoint, they were not put into separate document libraries like I had done before, and after they were uploaded, the folders were deleted so I can't just upload them again.  I'm trying to accomplish the same thing, but I want to use regex with the SharePoint document libraries.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!